# Mis-Typed iCloud Email Address. Want to create new iCloud email address

Tags: email, icloud

I made a foolish mistake when creating my iCloud email address.  There was a misspelling that I did not catch.  Now, my iCloud email is unacceptable to me with this spelling error.  I understand that one can not edit the email address.

Items:  I have iPod Touch, iPod, iPhone, and iPad.

AppleID:  I have only one.  It is NOT a mismatch of iCloud email address to AppleID.

Default Email:  This is correct and it is NOT my iCloud id.

Actions taken so far:

1. on apple.com website, under account management, I deleted the verified iCloud email.
2. on the ipad, under settings/icloud I clicked "delete account" with addition option of delete everything in lieu of "keep on iPad"

Results:
/fail.
When I reactivate the iCloud on my iPad, the settings automatically revert to the unacceptable iCloud email with the mistyped/misspelled id.

What I Need Help With:
I need someone to help me identify the ways to do the following:

1. delete the old iCloud id that I don't want
2. create a new iCloud id (abc@me.com)
3. associate the new iCloud id with my AppleID and all my iDevices

Comment: I might be missing something but where in the steps so far did you create the correct email address?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Apple Support?

Answer (score 3):

There are two different ways around this problem.

The first to self help. If you haven't verify the email address that you probably can go back in and change it. Unless you just created this Apple ID hours ago  and can walk away from it and just create a second one that is correct, Apple asks for many other pieces of information such as birthday security questions to factor in front Acacian that would allow you to change the one piece of information that's wrong.

The second is to engage Apple customer support. The Apple support webpage will channel you to iCloud account support staff and it will typically be a web form where you can place your correct contact information and explained the mistake you made. They might be able to assist you with things that you can't do for yourself. Additionally, they speak many languages and can often educate you about your options better than a catchall procedure on the Internet can.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I mis-understand the problem, I think you *can* edit your email address:

- Log into iCloud.com
- In the upper right-hand corner of the home screen, click on your name.
- In the dialog that appears, click on the AppleID box which contains your contact email address. A new web-page appears.
- Click the Manage Account link on the right hand side of that page.
- Sign in (again) on this page with the same credentials (e-mail & password). Your name and your email address will both be presented with a link to edit each.  On the left side of this page will be links to edit your password and other account information.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry your out of luck, this is a much required feature, especially as in the developer beta there was no confirmation of email address. All you can do contact Apple and tell them people want this, and hope that they implement it, like they finally implemented like deleting photos from photostream.